# slowly changing dimension not opening , system getting hang every time while trying to open

Tags: ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I got one package to enhance some of the functionality of SSIS package, but while I am trying to open SCD to know the attributes mapping and keys mapping, SSIS package gets hang everytime, 
due to that I am unable to investigate the other things in that.

Kindly help me to understand what could be the reasons ?
Every time I need to close whole package while hangs, and have to open again to investigate further.

[image]

Comment: Mayank check for free memory and cpu uses in taski manager....

Comment: This has been resolved, I was pulling 9 Lakhs records in my table, due to this it got hanged, now it is working fine,